# How to get days and months number from a given days

Tags: php, get, days

I'm going to write a function to print a number of days left between two dates. I would like it to tell the months and days left. For example:

```
45 days = 1month, 15 days
65 days = 2months, 5 days
10 days = 10 days
```

So I tried:

```
<?
$days=50;

if($days>"31"){
$time=$days/30;
}
echo $time;//1.67 month
?>
```

According to the code above. I expect the result to be like:

```
1 month, 20 days
```

Could you guys please suggest.

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be like that according to that code?

Comment: which months? just the ones with 30 days?

Comment: The length of a month varies - you're assuming that *all* months are 30 days long. That sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Not tested, but looks fine http://www.linein.org/blog/2010/04/01/find-years-and-months-between-two-dates-in-php/#commentform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$days = 50;

if ($days > 31){
    $month = floor($days/30); // return lowest whole integer
    $days = $days % 30; // calculate left days
}

echo $month . " => " . $days; // output `1 => 20`
```

Comment: @Wilf It may *work* but it's not accurate. If accuracy is important for your application, then this question is impossible without actually knowing the "from" and "to" times. Just having a difference in days is not adequate. For example, if it's February 1st and I say 29 days, your code won't say "1 month" even though it's now March.

Comment: @ColinMorelli, thanks for your recommendations but this is enough for my need. The accuracy is another issue that I'm worry about. But my app is needs only an estimation so the user would know how long their registration be expired. By the way if you could make another accurate version, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Get the month number for both months and subtract. Add in calculation for year change

Get day of months for both dates. If date2 > date1, subtract and you have the number of days, else remove 1 from month count and sumteact date

Comment: LobsterMan, Nice try but your instructions is useless to me. Thank you.

Comment: My answer will produce an accurate month/day number, but yes, I didn't spell out the code as I was on a mobile device. If you have a basic understanding of php, writing the code from my psudocode would take 2 minutes, and if not, then want's the point of your question

Comment: Lobsterman, Thank you for your kindness. Please don't go too far since I might beg you for some help. :)