# How can I get the number of days in a given month

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wan to get the number of days in a given month in php for reporting purpose
like this [image]

Comment: Have you read the manual? This question has been covered here many times and the answers are also in the manual.

Comment: [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: ok thanks i will check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get days and months number from a given days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941957/how-to-get-days-and-months-number-from-a-given-days)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$month=8;
$year=2016;
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
```